# How can we create UI code of number with line (image attached) in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can we create UI code of number with line (image attached) in a flutter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is horizontal stepper

Check this article

https://developer.school/tutorials/how-to-use-the-flutter-stepper-widget-flutter-2-6-0